# Comparing two array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form used to void, dismiss, amend and correct citations. A void can not be done in conjucntion with a dismissal, amendment, or correction.  If you need to void and amend, you complete two forms. You can however do a dismissal, amendment and/or correction on the same form. I have two arrays created based on the variables from the form. One array has the variables from the void section, the other array has all the other variables.

I am trying to create a rule that compares the void to all others.  I want to be able to check if any void variables are != "" and any of the other variables are != "" and then give an error message.

```
if($_POST[$all_other_fields] !== "" && $_POST[$void_fields] !== "")
                {
                  $all_ok = false;
        $citation_error_msg = "Blah, Blah Blah";
                 }
```

What I have done, unwittingly, is stated ALL varriables from both arrays must != "".  I want to say if even one variable from both arrays != "", then error message.

I am not sure how to make the comparison.

Comment: It's kind of impossible to help without knowing what $all_other_fields and $void_fields are.

Comment: The $all_other_fields represents the non-void array (41 variables) and the $void_fields represents the void array (2 variables).  So if either of the void variables and just one of the non-void variables !=="" then I need the error message.  I hope that helps, cause I know I need it.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're saying that if a void field is filled out, throw an error if someone fills out other sections?  I might restructure my form into a paged form, where you ask what the user wishes to do and then present them with a specific form to do it.  Having extraneous fields on a form just makes things confusing for the user.

In any event, if you stick with your current form design, you'll need to have an array of void field names against which you'll check your $_POST.  Something like:

```
$vf_flag=false;
$void_fields=array('vf1','vf2','vf3');
    foreach($void_fields as $vf) {
      if(!isset($_POST[$vf])) continue;
      $vf_flag=true;
      break; //only need one error
    }
$nonvf_flag=false;
//do the same as above except with a non_voidfields array()

if($nonvf_flag && $vf_flag) $citation_msg='blah blah blah';
```

This is a verbose way, but it's straightforward.  You could also do it with `array_filter()` and a callback.

Comment: I already had the two arrays created.  I simply substituted my variables in the appropriate places.  I am confused with the IF statement.  What is -if($nonvf_flag && $vf_flag)- saying? They are what?  I don't understand.  It looks like something is missing.

I like your idea of a paged form, this is govt and we never do anything the easy way, although I am trying to streamline the way we do business.

Comment: @George Garman: the $vf_flag is set to TRUE if one or more of the void $_POST fields exists. The $nonvf_flag is set to TRUE if one or more of the other $_POST fields is set.  If both flags are TRUE, then there is a problem. `if($nonvf_flag && $vf_flag)` is the same as `if($nonvf_flag==true && $vf_flag==true)`. 

Your original method: `$_POST[$array] !==''` is saying that the *scalar* value stored in `$_POST[$array]` is not *identical* to empty string.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.  I have gone over it and over it, and I even used your variable names but I am getting the following error:

PHP Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in D:\Resume\eCitation\Civil_VDAC_Validation.php on line 77

Line 77 is the first Break;  That is occurring with the form fields empty, if that matters.

Comment: @George-Garman : If you are getting an error like 'Cannot break/continue 1 level' it is because the break is not inside a control structure like foreach, while or switch (`if` doesn't count).  See http://ca3.php.net/break.  Lastly, I just noticed a syntax error in my code on the `if(!isset` I'm missing the closing parenthesis.  Sorry about that.